# Concatenate lists in Clojure Without Using concat

Tags: exception, clojure

I am new to clojure, and am trying to understand how to concatenate lists without using the concat function.

```
(defn append  [list1, list2]
  (cond
    (nil? list1) list2
    :else (cons (first list1)
            (append (rest list1) (list2)))))
```

When I run the above code, I get:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast 
   to clojure.lang.IFn  user/append
```

Reading from previous stackoverflow questions, it is because the `cond` expression is in double parentheses. I don't believe that I do.

Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clojure, parentheses mean "function call". Thus the expression:

```
(list2)
```

means call a function that the `list2` variable points at.  This is the source of the error and the message `clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`

---

Notes:

1. When a `cond` has only 2 branches, it is usually clearer to just a plain `if` expression.
2. Clojure code ignores commas, so they are normally never included in source code.
3. Consider carefully the difference between `rest` and `next`:

```
    (rest []) => ()
    (next []) => nil
```

You may wish to carefully study the Clojure CheatSheet and other [documention listed here](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn append
   [l1 l2 & [acc]]
   (cond (and (empty? l1) (empty? l2)) (reverse acc)
         (empty? l1) (append l1 (rest l2) (cons (first l2) acc))
         :else (append (rest l1) l2 (cons (first l1) acc))))
```

or:

```
(defn append
  ([l1 l2]
   (append l1 l2 '()))
  ([l1 l2 acc]
   (cond (and (empty? l1) (empty? l2)) (reverse acc)
         (empty? l1) (append l1 (rest l2) (cons (first l2) acc))
         :else (append (rest l1) l2 (cons (first l1) acc)))))
```

```
;; or using vectors and conj
(defn vec-append
  [v1 v2]
  (cond (empty? v2) v1
        :else (vec-append (conj v1 (first v2)) (rest v2))))

(defn append
   [l1 l2]
   (seq (vec-append (vec l1) (vec l2))))
```